# PHP, MySQL: question on how to "sync" two databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

Note: my question is in the last paragraph.

I have multiple sources of files that get inserted into a database (call it process/database A). These files contain the same type of information but in different formats (i.e. different column headers, orders, number of columns, etc.), but when process A puts them into a unified table, and it is nice and neat. I need this data from multiple sources also inserted into another database (process/database B), but I'm not sure what is the best way of doing this. DB B is part of a software we use. It is not open-source, but DB connection can be made.

We already have process A up and running for a while. Process B is something new to improve physical workflow at the warehouse. I think since the data is already unified in process A, it seems to me that I should pull this unified data and insert it into B. This will save me the repetitive work of remapping everything for process B.

My question is, if I want to "sync" these two databases, what would be the optimal approach? It's not exactly "syncing," I suppose, because the two tables (only need to reference one table on each DB) have different columns. I see these approaches..

1. Check the entire DB's and pull from DB A to insert to DB B for new data. However, DB B has over 50K rows. DB A is much smaller and growing slowly.
2. Have the user input a date from which to look for new data rows to insert from A to B.
3. Check the latest date (data rows are dated) in DB B, and insert accordingly.

Do you guys have any inputs? I'm not too familiar with MySQL processing speed, so I'm not sure if approach 1 is a good option. I'm also not sure what some conventions (if any) are for these types of tasks. I imagine it isn't a too-uncommon thing to do. But (1) seems to be a more complete way of doing things. Any comments or alternative options are appreciated. I'd like to keep things in PHP as it will be a feature on a web application. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql clustering
Check it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster

Comment: that looks a bit complicated for my level of PHP MySQL knowledge. Also, database B I mentioned above is part of a commercial software. Inserting outside data is not supported (but it shouldn't interfere with the software).. I can't really mess around with it other than inserting data on one table in the DB.